# React Dropdown Value Not Set to default after Clear Filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had a Company Dropdown Component and Sidebar.js to call the component. When i clicked on clear filter button, the products displayed are set to default value. But the value& text of Company dropdown still displaying old value. For example,"Honda".
The behaviour seems correct as the products will display to default value but doesnt work on dropdown

**Sidebar.js**

```
import Category from "./Category/Category";
import Model from "./Model/Model";
import Company from "./Company/Company";

import "./Sidebar.css";

const Sidebar = ({ handleChange, selectedCompany, resetPage }) => {
  const [companyValue, setCompanyValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("companyValue:", companyValue);
  }, [companyValue]); // Log companyValue whenever it changes

  const handleCompanyChange = (event) => {
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    setCompanyValue(newValue); // Update the companyValue state
    handleChange(event);
    resetPage();
  };
  

  const handleModelChange = (event) => {
    handleChange(event);
    resetPage();
  };

  const handleCategoryChange = (event) => {
    handleChange(event);
    resetPage();
  };

  const clearAllFilters = () => {
    setCompanyValue("");
    handleChange({ target: { name: "company", value: "" } });
    handleChange({ target: { name: "model", value: "" } });
    handleChange({ target: { name: "category", value: "" } });
    resetPage();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <section className="sidebar">
        <div className="logo-container">
          <h1></h1>
        </div>
        
        <Company handleChange={handleCompanyChange} value={companyValue} />
        <Model
          handleChange={handleModelChange}
          selectedCompany={selectedCompany}
        />
        <Category handleChange={handleCategoryChange} />
        <button onClick={clearAllFilters}>Clear All Filters</button>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

**Company.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./Company.css";

function Company({ handleChange }) {
  const handleCompanyChange = (event) => {
    handleChange(event); // Invoke the handleChange function for company changes
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="sidebar-title">Company</h2>
      <div>
        <select onChange={handleCompanyChange} className="company-dropdown" name="company">
          <option value="">All</option>
          <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
          <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Company;
```

Comment: Hi Jesscy ! Have you checked the below answer? Let us know please :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to pass the state `companyValue` to `Company` and use it there as the value of `select` to be completely synced:

```
<Company handleChange={handleCompanyChange} value={companyValue} />
```

```
function Company({ handleChange, value }) {
  const handleCompanyChange = (event) => {
    handleChange(event); // Invoke the handleChange function for company changes
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="sidebar-title">Company</h2>
      <div>
        <select  value={value} onChange={handleCompanyChange} className="company-dropdown" name="company">
          <option value="">All</option>
          <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
          <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```